# get root path of my server in html

Tags: html, redirect

it's pretty simple but is kind of hard to explain. I have this image

```
<img src="../../Image/Picture.JPG" />
```

But i don't want use `../..` I just want to know if it's a symbol that take to root folder. to accomplish something like this. In other words i'm looking for a character that give's me the root where are deploy the html

```
<img src="rootFolder/Image/Picture.JPG" />
```

**Also i tried like this but it doesn't work**

```
<img src="~/Image/Picture.JPG" />
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`/` is the relative path to the "root" of your server (that is to say the [DocumentRoot](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#documentroot) of the domain, assuming you are using a simple Apache setup).

Try:

```
<img src="/Image/Picture.JPG" />
```

Answer (score 1):

"/" will take you to the root.  Try "/image/picture.jpg" if the folder "image" is in your root directory.

NOTE:  Some shared hosts perceived root is not the same as what you would expect.  Be aware of that.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are looking for "/"?

Just put / as the first character of your link and it will point to the root directory of the website.

Answer (score 1):

I know there's a character for it.  I think it's like "/Images/Picture.JPG", leave out the ..